# Check Resharper code issues in a test

Tags: .net, testing, resharper

Resharper code issues inspection is great at finding problems, but it is difficult to stop the number of issues from becoming unmanageable.

Is there a way to write a test that will fail if there are resharper code issues? I would like code issues to break the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liam, take a look at TeamCity 7.0 (currently in [EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/TeamCity+EAP)).
It can run ReSharper analyses at the server's side.